# Crash after NSURLSession task resume

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am using NSURLSession to do my network calls. Eventhough I am in the foreground, I prefer to use backgroundSession configuration because even if my app crashes the network call won't fail. However, after crash when I create the session with the same identifier the system calls my delegate with a non-existing file location. How can that be possible ? Will the tasks not auto join after I re-create the session ?